# Adding a stopping criteria in a function as an input parameter in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have something like the following loop in `R` which I can run for a time duration or number of iteration:

```
n_iteration <- 1

time_elapsed <-0
t1 <- Sys.time()
```

To run it for a particular duration:

```
while (time_elapsed <= 10) {
  
  t2 <- Sys.time()
  time_elapsed <- time_elapsed + (t2-t1)
  print(paste0('Time elapsed:', time_elapsed, ' Iteration no:', n_iteration))
  
  n_iteration <- n_iteration+1
  
}
```

To run it for a number of loops:

```
while (n_iteration <= 10) {
  
  t2 <- Sys.time()
  time_elapsed <- time_elapsed + (t2-t1)
  print(paste0('Time elapsed:', time_elapsed, ' Iteration no:', n_iteration))
  
  n_iteration <- n_iteration+1
  
}
```

Running either of them will solve the purpose. But how can this be wrapped in a function where I can mention which criteria to use for stopping? I want to achieve this without repeating the code.

My tedious and sub-optimal approach:

```
loop_func <- function(stopping_criteria='STEPS') {
  n_iteration <- 1
  
  time_elapsed <-0
  t1 <- Sys.time()
  
  if(stopping_criteria=='TIME'){
    while (time_elapsed <= 10) {
      
      t2 <- Sys.time()
      time_elapsed <- time_elapsed + (t2-t1)
      print(paste0('Time elapsed:', time_elapsed, ' Iteration no:', n_iteration))
      
      n_iteration <- n_iteration+1
      
    }
  }else{
    while (n_iteration <= 10) {
      
      t2 <- Sys.time()
      time_elapsed <- time_elapsed + (t2-t1)
      print(paste0('Time elapsed:', time_elapsed, ' Iteration no:', n_iteration))
      
      n_iteration <- n_iteration+1
      
    }
  }
  
}
```

Can this be done without copying the `while` loop twice?

Comment: @RonakShah I have added my approach. Basically, I want to yield the output without repeating the ```while``` loop as I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can write another function for `while` loop -

```
while_function <- function(x) {
  while (x <= 10) {
    t2 <- Sys.time()
    time_elapsed <- time_elapsed + (t2-t1)
    print(paste0('Time elapsed:', time_elapsed, ' Iteration no:', x))
    x <- x+1
    
  }
}

loop_func <- function(stopping_criteria='STEPS') {
  n_iteration <- 1
  time_elapsed <-0
  t1 <- Sys.time()
  if(stopping_criteria=='TIME'){
    while_function(time_elapsed)
  }else{
    while_function(n_iteration)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the purpose to some extent. But what if I have multiple parameters which I need to give input to the while function. Can that be done with this approach?